# Alternate interpretation of p-value

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value

I have got a p-value of .0166 on a hypothesis test on comparison of hourly wages for different countries. Would it be right to make a a conclusive remark that 
“We can be 98.34% confident [1-.0166] that rejecting the null hypothesis and concluding that hourly wages are different for countries is the right conclusion.”

Comment: I don't think "98.34% confident" has any well-defined technical meaning. Most people would probably take it as saying that the probability of the null's being true is 98.34%, which isn't what you want.